Помогите с задачей по Python
По приезде на дачу мама забрала ноутбук у Хакера Петра и отправила его за инструментами
в сарай. На сарае висит кодовый замок. Секретную комбинацию мама записала на руке у
Петра. Кодовый замок представляет собой n вращающихся дисков с написанными на них цифрами
от 0 до 9. Хакер Пётр должен повернуть некоторые из дисков так, чтобы последовательность цифр на
дисках образовала секретную комбинацию. За одно действие он может прокрутить один из
дисков на одну цифру вперед или назад. В частности, за одно действие можно перейти от
цифры 0 к цифре 9 и наоборот. Какое минимальное количество действий ему для этого потребуется?
Входные данные
В первой строке записано единственное целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000) — количество дисков
на кодовом замке.
Во второй строке записана строка из n цифр — исходное положение дисков.
В третьей строке записана строка из n цифр — комбинация, открывающая замок.
Выходные данные
Выведите единственное целое число — минимальное количество действий, за которое
Хакер Пётр откроет замок.
def min_actions(secret, current):
    actions = 0
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        diff = int(secret[i]) -  int(current[i])
        if diff < 0:
            diff += 10
        actions += diff
    return actions

secret = "12345"
current = "00000"
min_actions = min_actions(secret, current)
print(min_actions)


Ну почти всё же сделали. Увеличение actions вынесите из-под ифа. И  "на одну цифру вперед или назад" подразумевает, что нужно выбрать минимум из двух поворотов.

Is this your homework Larry ?

а про повороты, то есть надо поменять количество в actions?

У вас сейчас actions обновляется, только если разность отрицательная была, а должна в любом случае. сдвиньте влево. А разницу - например, 7 и 3 образуют две разницы - 4 и 6, нужно выбрать меньшую

все равно ответ не сходиться... может как-то по-другому можно решить?

Одну логическую ошибку исправили, а вторую нет.

Как я уже сказал в комментарии, нужно выбрать минимальную из разниц "вверх" или "вниз"
def min_actions(secret, current):
    actions = 0
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        a = int(secret[i])
        b = int(current[i])
        diff = min((a-b)%10, (b-a)%10)
        print(diff)
        actions += diff
    return actions


все я догнал! спасибо огромное

ОК, не забывайте принимать ответы
